# UWP problem with library using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp, active-directory

I am working on a UWP application and I'm trying to call a library which uses `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` but it keeps throwing the following exception:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate' from assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.17.2.31801, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

I've tried updating the version to 5.2.6 but to no avail. I've also tried installing the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` NuGet package directly into the UWP project, yet again to no avail.

I'm thinking this package is just not compatible with UWP? Because it works fine in a .NET Core or Framework console app. Is there a way I can shim it or force compatibility?

Comment: please check your project target  and min version go to the project properties and check

Comment: @ketan Target: Universal Windows, Target Version: Windows 10, version 1903 (10.0; 17763), Minimum Version: Windows 10, version 1903 (10.0; Build 18362)

Comment: try to change your minimum version and then  build the application and then try to install may be there is version issue